# Python - Best GUI library for the job?

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been using WxPython and I've tried Tk, but it seems that, while both are good and I'll likely use them for other projects, neither of those appear to be capable of accomplishing the things that I want for my current project (which is fine, they're good at what they do).

Basically what I'm looking for is something that will allow me to make rich graphical GUIs. My specific goal is a window that will draw bitmap buttons, resize the parent window automatically to fit them, and possibly animate the resize with a slide effect and have the buttons fade in. Also being able to have my own window border style instead of the inbuilt one is important to me.

This particular project will be Windows only, so non-portable libraries are fine in this case, though portable ones would be great too.

If I missed how this can be done in either WxPython or Tk, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PySide: http://www.pyside.org/

> The PySide project provides
>   LGPL-licensed Python bindings for the
>   Qt cross-platform application and UI
>   framework. PySide Qt bindings allow
>   both free open source and proprietary
>   software development and ultimately
>   aim to support all of the platforms as
>   Qt itself.

The Windows version of PySide is quite new and may be considered as a beta version. PySide is API compatible with PyQt.

Answer (score 7):

How about PyQt?

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

Answer (score 3):

Just sharing my opinion: [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home).

Innovative open-source library. Supports both 2.x and 3.x versions of Python.

> Kivy - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications
>   that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.

Kivy is based on OpenGL ES 2 and includes native multi-touch for each platform and Android/iOS. It’s an event-driven framework based around a main loop, and is thus also suitable for game development.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/). Its a library for python that makes using OpenGL very easy. You can draw pretty good 2d interfaces using Quads.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what is best because that is subjective but I can give you another option: [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)

> PyGTK lets you to **easily create programs with a graphical user interface** using the Python programming language. The underlying GTK+ library provides all kind of visual elements and utilities for it and, if needed, you can develop full featured applications for the GNOME Desktop.
>
> PyGTK applications are truly **multiplatform** and they're able to run, unmodified, on Linux, Windows, MacOS X and other platforms.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for since I don't want to have to have GTK+ installed on systems that will be using the application, but it's  certainly valid suggestion otherwise, so +1

Comment: Just mentioning that you have to install QT as well on systems wich are using your application...